# Material Button is closing my application in Virtual Device

Tags: android, material-design

I've created a new project and i'm using material button. I've noticed that when I put the material button in my xml file, it closes my application in AVD. Any solutions? Thanks!

Here's my activity xml:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF007235"

        android:text="Next"
        app:icon="@drawable/arrow_forward"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.946"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textureView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />
```

my styles.xml:

```
    <resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green_light</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

my build gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

    // ARCore (Google Play Services for AR) library.
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.23.0'

    // Obj - a simple Wavefront OBJ file loader
    // https://github.com/javagl/Obj
    implementation 'de.javagl:obj:0.2.1'

}
```

Comment: You'll need to include the stack trace for us to be able to see the issue!

Comment: @HenryTwist I'm still new to android studio so I think phrased my question wrong. What I meant was my application is closing in the Virtual Device when I open an activity that contains Material Button in the layout xml. Thanks!

Comment: Closing without an error?